# how to check the last two characters are digits in hive?

Tags: sql, hive

in sql I use

```
regexp_instr(substr(trim(col),1,2),'^([0-9]){2}$') = 1
```

but I not sure how can I check this in hive, I tried `regexp_extract` instead `regexp_instr` but I just have the last digit then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect something like this to work:

```
where col rlike '[0-9]{2}$'
```

Your code has a `trim()`; you can include that logic in the expression as well:

```
where col rlike '[0-9]{2}[ ]*$'
```

I would recommend such simplified logic in your original system as well.

Answer (score 0):

`substr(col,length(col)-1)` returns last two characters

`cast(substr(col,length(col)-1) as int)` returns NULL if last two characters is not a digit

You can check `case when cast(substr(col,length(col)-1) as int) is NULL/is not NULL then ...`

examples:

`select substr('abcdef12',length('abcdef12')-1)` returns 12

`cast(substr('abcdef12',length('abcdef12')-1) as int)` returns 12

`cast(substr('abcdef1x',length('abcdef1x')-1) as int)` returns NULL

Add a trim() if necessary